# mySQL Timezones Conversion

Tags: php, mysql

In my database, updateTime is set to TIMESTAMP and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.  But when I display the data, the time that was recorded in the database is not my local timezone but rather 3 hours later.  How can I subtract those 3 hours by converting this SQL statement? Can I use CONVERT_TZ somehow inline with this statement? I don't know how to do it.

```
SELECT updates.updateID, updates.windowStatus, updates.onDeck, updates.updateComments,    TIME_FORMAT(`updateTime`,'%r') AS showtime FROM updates ORDER BY updates.updateID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Server Time Zone can be set by each client (per-connection) in order to receive the data in other TZ than UTC. In order to do that, you just have to use:

```
SET time_zone = timezone;
```

The value of `timezone` can be given as an offset of UTC ('+10:00', '-6:00', ...) or as a named time zone (such as  'Europe/Helsinki', 'US/Eastern', or 'MET'). Therefore, you can set your own TZ in order to receive your data in '+3:00', if I'm not mistaken.

Take into account that this offset done by the mysql server only affects `NOW()`, `CURTIME()` and values stored in and retrieved from `TIMESTAMP` columns (which is what you're looking for).

You could otherwise use

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

to get the global and client-specific timezones.

There's more relevant info (and this is actually a sum-up of what I wrote) at: [Time-zone support (mysql.com)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html).

In your case, you could have something like this:

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_casualconnnect, $casualconnnect); 

$set_tz_query = "SET time_zone = '+1:00'";
mysql_query($set_tz_query, $casualconnnect) or die(mysql_error()); 

$query_Recordset2 = "SELECT updates.updateID, updates.windowStatus, 
    TIME_FORMAT(`updateTime`,'%r') AS showtime, updates.onDeck, updates.updateComments 
    FROM updates ORDER BY updates.updateID DESC LIMIT 1"; 

$Recordset2 = mysql_query($query_Recordset2, $casualconnnect) or die(mysql_error()); 
$row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2); $totalRows_Recordset2 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset2); 

?>
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand how to make this work. I don't think I can set the timezone for the server.

Comment: Well, just make a query with 'SET time_zone = timezone;' and as long as you don't create a new connection or break the existent, you'll get your data in your time zone. Otherwise, you could do both queries at the same time with a dot-comma between them.

Comment: Like this?

SET time_zone = timezone;SELECT updates.updateID, updates.windowStatus, updates.onDeck, updates.updateComments,    TIME_FORMAT(`updateTime`,'%r') AS showtime FROM updates ORDER BY updates.updateID DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: You have to add you timezone. For example, mine would be `SET time_zone = '+1:00';`

Comment: Okay, I'm using dreamweaver and this is the code that I have...dreamweaver says that is invalid mysql..

$query_Recordset2 = "SET time_zone = '+1:00'; SELECT updates.updateID, updates.windowStatus, TIME_FORMAT(`updateTime`,'%r') AS showtime, updates.onDeck, updates.updateComments FROM updates ORDER BY updates.updateID DESC LIMIT 1";

Comment: Hmm, no idea why. Have you tried it directly over mysql to catch the error? Was the query working before you added the timezone setting?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT updates.updateID, updates.windowStatus, TIME_FORMAT(`updateTime`,'%r') AS' at line 1

Comment: Yes the query runs before adding the additional SET

Comment: If it runs without the SET, try doing two different queries, one with the SET and other with the SELECT

Comment: When I removed the apostrophy : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT updates.updateID, updates.windowStatus, TIME_FORMAT(updateTime,'%r') AS s' at line 1

Comment: Yep, the apostrophy stuff had nothing to do with it. As I said: brainfart. Try doing two separate queries as I suggested in the previous comment :)

Comment: I am making the query SET time_zone directly in phpmyadmin will this work?

Comment: It will not be reflected in the Dreamweaver query, as they are different connections. If you're running your own server and want to change mysql server's time_zone with `SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;`
What I meant is to do to queries, one followed by the other, in php as you where doing up till now.

Comment: I'm not sure where to put that into my code. `mysql_select_db($database_casualconnnect, $casualconnnect);
$query_Recordset2 = "SELECT updates.updateID, updates.windowStatus, TIME_FORMAT(`updateTime`,'%r') AS showtime, updates.onDeck, updates.updateComments FROM updates ORDER BY updates.updateID DESC LIMIT 1";
$Recordset2 = mysql_query($query_Recordset2, $casualconnnect) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2);
$totalRows_Recordset2 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset2);

Comment: I do not priveleges to set global timezone on my server

Comment: Ok, I just edited my post so you have it easy to copy :)
Try and tell me what you've got, please.

Comment: So basically I just have to give it a name and then call it using mysql_query?  Your code works brilliantly by the way. I just had to set it to '-7:00'!

Comment: I'm glad it worked :) (Sorry I had to leave, I had to sleep :P).
What you're actually doing is doing to different queries, but both on the same connection. In the first one you change the connection timezone and in the second one you get your results.